Issue with chai-http middleware when using dynamic imports in chai version 5.1.1
I am currently using npm chai version 5.1.1 which now only supports import and not require. I have used dynamic imports which are working fine. However, when I am using the chai-http middleware with chai, it is not working as expected and is giving me an error.
Here is the syntax I am using:
let chai, expect, chaiHttp, request;

(async() => {
  expect = (await import ('chai')).expect;
  chai = (await import('chai')).default;
  chaiHttp = (await import('chai-http')).default;
  chai.use(chaiHttp);
})();

it("should return a 200 response", async function() {
    const response = await chai.request(app).get('/abc');
    expect(response).to.have.status(200);
});

It appears that chai.use(chaiHttp); is not functioning as expected due to the asynchronous behaviour of JavaScript. I am not sure why this is happening.
Can anyone help me understand this issue and suggest a possible fix?

change like this
  const use = (await import('chai')).use;
  expect = (await import ('chai')).expect;
  chaiHttp = (await import('chai-http')).default;
  chai = use(chaiHttp);

